# Adding a Quartz job to a running SQL server

Tags: sql-server, quartz-scheduler

I have an SQL DB with a scheduled Quartz job already running in the system for a while. 
I’d like to add a new job, but, whenever I try to, I keep messing up the existing jobs. 
here’s my job descriptions (part of them):

[image: quartz scheduling]

My main  problem is that I don’t know which values to start with when I insert a new job. 
I know it’s a little bit obscure but any pointer in the right direction will be nice.